# Make listview search faster

Tags: android, listview

I have been able to filter list items in a listview based on file name using textwatcher. However, I am not sure if this will cause longer execution time and frozen frames given the for loops usage and traversal through the files list.

My code for searching in listview :

```
edsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            List<File> ccpt = new ArrayList<File>();
            String text = edsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

             for(int i=0;i<flLst.size();i++){
                 if(flLst.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                     ccpt.add(flLst.get(i));
                 }

             }

            FlAdapter mAdapterx = new FlAdapter(ListFiles.this, R.layout.fl_list_item, ccpt);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapterx);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

This for loop traverses through the list and can make the dynamic search slow for a list that is too big. Is there a way to make this faster?

I tried Binary search after a suggestion from comments but it actually freezes the app so I am not sure if my implementation is spot on, also  if a list item also contains the searched text as a part of its name I am listing that as well:

```
public List<File> binarySearch(ArrayList<File> array, String value)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = array.size() - 1;

    ArrayList<File> temps = new ArrayList<File>();

    while (start <= end)
    {
        int middle = start + (end - start)/2;
        if (array.get(middle).getName().contains(value)) {
            temps.add(array.get(middle));
           // return true;
        }
        else if (array.get(middle).getName().compareTo(value)>0)
        {
            end = middle - 1;
        }
        else start = middle + 1;
    }
   return temps;
}
```

Comment: You can do a binary search if your keep your list sorted...                           Thus you have `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)` for the search.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly Actually I do not just need to search for one item but if a list item also contains the searched text as a part of its name  I am listing that as well. So I did try binary search but I am not sure if my implementation is spot on. I am adding my binary search code as well but I wanted a method which most developers use for search with compatibility since API 9.

Comment: If the search criteria is "contains" is like running a query with a LIKE you need a full scan, which is the same as sweeping all the records of the list sequentially. At most you can divide the list in parts and run separate searches on different threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care for memory uses then you can cache your `flLst.get(i).getName().toLowerCase()` on a list of string as list is **modified.** Since there is one one correspondence between cache and listitems then perform searches on cache and get item from `flLst.` It will perform better as more and more searches are performed.

**EDIT**

```
flLst = getYourListLigic ();
ArrayList <String> cache = new ArrayList <>();
for(int i=0;i<flLst.size();i++){
    cache.add (flLst.get(i).getName().toLowerCase());

edsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        List<File> ccpt = new ArrayList<File>();
        String text = edsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

         for(int i=0;i<flLst.size();i++){
             if(cache.get(i).contains(text)){
                 ccpt.add(flLst.get(i));
             }

         }

        FlAdapter mAdapterx = new FlAdapter(ListFiles.this, R.layout.fl_list_item, ccpt);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapterx);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you support your method with some code as I am not familiar with this type of caching?